# Accessing sub-directories in an archived folder

Tags: vba, zip, archive

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening/Midnight SO,

This has become an increasingly frustrating issue - 48 hours in, I've looked at every article I could find. I'll first describe the problem and it's goal, and then what I've done thus far.

### Objective

There is a drive with terabytes of archived (zipped) folders. Within each of these zipped folders is a folder hierarchy that may be one level deep, may be several layers (of sub-directories) deep. In each of these zipped archives lies a single file, call it "diamond.xls". Unfortunately, each archive may put it in a different sub-directory, so we'll have to crawl through every sub-directory looking for "diamond.xls". The challenge has been writing a VBA script that can explore a zipped folder, search through any/all sub-directories, find "diamond.xls", and if found, open and copy the data within to a new sheet.

### Work Thus Far

There are many articles written about extracting a single file out of a zipped folder. However, I haven't seen one that is able to crawl through sub-directories in the zipped drive. One SO contributor stated that zipped drives are flat, however when I go through the .items() of a zipped drive, it seems to only return the first level, leading me to believe this may be incorrect. Here is my current code:

```
Public Function goThroughZip(ByRef strZipFilename, ByVal strDstDir, ByRef strFilename)
    'Script based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716587/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-archive-in-vba-without-unzipping-the-archive

    Dim intOptions, objShell, objSourceItems, objTarget

    ' Create the required Shell objects
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    ' Create a reference to the files and folders in the ZIP file
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSourceItems = objShell.Namespace(strZipFilename).Items()

    'Browse through Items
    Dim objSourcCol As Collection
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim tempItem As Variant

    For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
        tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i).GetFolder.Items  '<-- more on this below
        Debug.Print (tempItem)
    Next i


    ' Create a reference to the target folder
    'Set objTarget = objShell.Namespace(strDstDir)
    'intOptions = glngcCopyHereDisplayProgressBox
    'Debug.Print ("objTarget " & objTarget)
    ' UnZIP the files
    'objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions

    ' Release the objects
    Set objSource = Nothing
    Set objTarget = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing

    goThroughZip = 1
End Function
```

This code is far from complete. I've been trying to understand how to play with the .nameSpace method and the folder items methods.

```
Set objSourceItems = objShell.Namespace(strZipFilename).Items()
```

returns an array of Folder2 type items, the first level in the archived folder (hooray!)

So now according to [MS Dev Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787800(v=vs.85).aspx), I should be able to use the method .item(i as variant) to retrieve a folderItem object (and access to the folder).

```
Dim i as Variant
Dim tempItem as Variant
for i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i)
    Debug.Print(TypeName(tempItem))
Next i
```

Returns a bunch of strings... Not FolderITem objects..  Hmm, well, let's pretend it is a folderitem and see what happens:

```
Dim i as Variant
Dim tempItem as Variant
for i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i).GetFolder().Items()
    Debug.Print(TypeName(tempItem))
Next i
```

Now we are returning FolderItemVerbs.

Let's try modifying the code inside the loop to:

```
tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i).Path()
Debug.Print (tempItem)
```

Returns a bunch of pathnames that look good, i.e. "C;\archive.zip\folder1"

What if we take that pathname and feed that into another NameSpace:

```
For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempPath = objSourceItems.Item(i).Path()
    tempSourceItems = objShell.Namespace(tempPath).Items()
    Debug.Print (TypeName(tempSourceItems))
Next i
```

Again, FolderItemVerbs.. Not A folderItem. Let's make sure that these are indeed folders:

```
For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i).isFolder()
    Debug.Print (tempItem & " : " & objSourceItems.Item(i))
Next i
```

True - they are folders.

What if we just simply:

```
For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i)
    Debug.Print (tempItem.items())
Next i
```

Nothing.. returns nothing at all. I know that there are sub-folders and files in those folders. What's going on?

How do I access these sub-folders and find the diamond.xls in each archive?

Thank you all so much for your time and consideration. My manager has been demanding a solution soon - you've helped me a great deal!

With gratitude,

Zac

---

*EDIT: Strange observance:

```
For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i).Size
    Debug.Print (tempItem)    '<-- Returns Longs that show size
Next i

For i = 0 To objSourceItems.Count - 1
    tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i)
    Debug.Print (tempItem.size) '<-- Returns nothing
Next i
```

I think I'm missing some fundamental aspects of VBA...

Comment: In regards to your edit and "strange observance" Try this instead. `Set tempItem = objSourceItems.Item(i)`. You're not getting an object instance currently, but are getting the item's default property instead. [How to avoid default property gotchyas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342869/how-to-avoid-default-property-gotchas-in-vba) is relevant, but doesn't explain the issue very well. [Difference in type between using and not using Set keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11089040/3198973) does a pretty good job of explaining it though.

Comment: Woah, that one word has made a world of difference! I'm not sure I'm quite home free (or going home after work tonight just yet), but now my variables are returning folderItems and I have been able to access another layer down! Thank you!

Comment: Yup, classic `Let` vs `Set` mistake. Happy I could help. Please be sure to upvote the questions and answers that helped you. I hope you get your zip directory issue worked out.

Comment: Hi ZAR, did you manage to resolve this issue? I have something similar coming up where I have to troll through `Archived` folders so just wondering if you had any luck?

Comment: @Zac I did, though I cant locate the code. I remember discovering that zip files are actually flat and the way I was opening the file in VBA made the difference

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you could point me in a direction (i.e. maybe how you opened the file), it would be much appreciated. Although, a code snippet as an answer is probably the best response :)